# Nested promise functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a button that I want to track when the user press it, and if the tracking ajax call returns data, then execute a promise, when thats all done, continue with the button event.

Below is what I have so far, however the button event and the 2nd promise fire at the same time. The button event isn't waiting for the 2nd promise to resolve

- Click button
- AJAX call records the event
- If AJAX doesn't return a question then alert hello.
- If the AJAX call returns a question, then build and open modal, when modal closes, then alert hello.

```js
$('.my_button').on('click', function() {
    ui_tracking('button_1').then(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});

function ui_tracking(type, payload) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var log_action = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/submit_action',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                type: type,
                payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
            },
            success: function(results, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (typeof(results) !== 'undefined' && results !== null) {
                    if (typeof(results.data) !== 'undefined' && results.data !== null) {
                        if (results.data.question) {
                            startQuestion(results.data.question).then(function () {
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }, function() {
                                deferred.reject();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                deferred.resolve();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        });
    };

    log_action();

    return deferred.promise();
}

function startQuestion(question_data) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var openQuestion = function () {
        $('#question-modal .modal-body .question').html(question_data.question).attr('data-question-id', question_data.id);

        $('#question-modal').modal('show').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            deferred.resolve();
            $('#question-modal').unbind('hidden.bs.modal');
        });
    };

    openQuestion();
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

sf

Comment: I think you need the javascript [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) feature.

Comment: @PabloDarde - as the Promises are supposed to be in series, Promise.all is of no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your success: callback calls `deferred.resolve();` straight away (at the end, after the if condition)

```
    success: function(results, textStatus, xhr) {
        if (typeof(results) !== 'undefined' && results !== null) {
            if (typeof(results.data) !== 'undefined' && results.data !== null) {
                if (results.data.question) {
                    startQuestion(results.data.question).then(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }, function() {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        // this gets called regardless of the above conditions!
        deferred.resolve();
```

Knowing $.ajax returns a (jQuery) Promise, I believe you could simplify ui_tracking function as follows:

```
function ui_tracking(type, payload) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/api/submit_action',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            type: type,
            payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }
    }).then(function(results) {
        if (results && results.data && results.data.question) {
            return startQuestion(results.data.question);
        }
    });
}
```

In the above .then, if the conditions are not met, the return is `undefined` ... basically the same thing as you were doing with `deferred.resolve()` - the returned Promise will be resolved to `undefined` once the ajax completes

However, if the conditions are all met, the return is the Promise returned by `startQuestion` - which will mean the returned Promise will be that which is returned by `startQuestion` - therefore your code will wait on that promise to resolve before continuing

Also, no need for error handling that simply returns a rejected promise - let the outer call handle errors

Alternatively, you could write the whole lot as

```
$('.my_button').on('click', function() {
    ui_tracking('button_1')
    .then(startQuestion)
    .then(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});

function ui_tracking(type, payload) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/api/submit_action',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            type: type,
            payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }
    });
}

function startQuestion(results) {
    var deferred;
    var openQuestion = function (question_data) {
        $('#question-modal .modal-body .question').html(question_data.question).attr('data-question-id', question_data.id);

        $('#question-modal').modal('show').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            deferred.resolve();
            $('#question-modal').unbind('hidden.bs.modal');
        });
    };
    if (results && results.data && results.data.question) {
        deferred = $.Deferred();
        openQuestion(results.data.question);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
}
```

Sure the logic has moved about, so maybe not exactly what you'd like

Comment: using the ajax promise worked perfectly for me. the rewrite at the end isn't the best of me since this has to be applied to many places and Im trying to consolidate things. thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate each "step" in a function returning a promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and then "chain" them.

This is a great post on executing promises in a series: http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/#executingpromisesinseries (you *may* need a polyfill for your promising: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)